# About the definition of PE

Tags: libraries

I know that binary executables in Windows belong to **PE**, but what about libraries like `.dll` or `.lib` files, do they belong to the category of **PE**?

And what about the executables in Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Wikipedia [Portable Executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable):

> Filename extension     .cpl, .exe, .dll, .ocx, .sys, .scr, .drv, .tlb

Linux uses [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

See also: [Comparison of executable file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_executable_file_formats)